# Mishnah Berurah's Safek on eating each day in Succah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sukkot, mishnah-berurah, vilna-gaon

The Mishnah Berurah (639,24) says that perhaps just like the Gra said on Pesah that there is a mitzvah to eat matzah every day of Pesah, so is there a mitzvah to eat bread and to say Birkat Leshev BaSukkah each day of Sukkot.

Why does the Mishnah Berurah have a Safek that one has a Mitzvah to eat in the Sukkah every day of Sukkot?

Comment: What if you don’t want to eat bread one day?

Comment: You have to eat bread in the sukkah because of בסוכות תשבו but if you eat it do you fulfill a different mitzvah, just like if you eat matzah when you don't have to you fulfill a mitzvah?

Answer (score 2):

With Pesach it says Shemos 13,6:שבעת ימים **תאכל** מצות which the Gra interprets that each Kzais of Matza one eats is a mitzva.

With Succos it says Vayikra 23,42:בסכת **תשבו** שבעת ימים and the Shulchan Aruch explains the Mitzva:כיצד מצות ישיבה בסוכה שיהיה **אוכל ושותה (וישן ומטייל)** (טור) ודר בסוכה כל שבעת הימים בין ביום ובין בלילה which means its a combined Mitzva of dwelling which includes eating drinking and sleeping but not necessarily a separate Mitzva for every piece of bread that you eat.

I think The Mishna brura is in doubt as to whether the main part of "Dwelling" is the eating, so each kzais of the bread which is the main part of the meal is fulfilling a separate Mitzva of Dwelling in the Succah. Alternatively, one only gets a Mitzva for normal dwelling which means eating 14 meals a week with no individual Mitzva for eating more (but of course one should eat in the Succah whenever one is hungry as if he were in his house).